# Accessing $_POST using a variable name

Tags: php

I am using PHP 7.1 trying to access $_POST From within a variable name.

```
$key = '_POST';
var_dump( ${$key} );die; // OR $$key
```

it throws a `Notice` saying:
`Undefined variable: _POST`

It's kinda strange cause this one works as expected

```
var_dump( ${'_POST'} );die;
```

I would like to know what is wrong in the first approach that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work can be read in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) for Superglobals:

> Superglobals cannot be used as variable variables inside functions or class methods.

So you can't access any Superglobals this way.